# Remove "Page" from Category archive

Tags: pagination, urls, archives

For the moment my site category archive URL show as

```
example.com/blog/category/all/page/2/
```

I want to remove "page" from slug so it should display as:

```
example.com/blog/category/all/2/
```

Any tips how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

In the backoffice of wordpress you can choose your own permalinks.

In Settings > Permalinks, you will be able to change that by your own structure.

You will have severals parameters, like `%year%`, `%postname%`, `%author%`, etc.

You will have to choose for your example : `example.com/blog/category/all/%postname%` .

The other idea, is maybe to create an article, to put this article in a specific category then your permalink will be as you want.